# php message sender with delay

Tags: php, mysql, sender

This code extract user ids from my database and send them a message. The issue is that is trying  to send the message to all users at the same time and my db goes down. I get error if I send it on to many users. Can someone help me to make it send messages to 1 user or 2 at the time and maybe some seconds delay betwen messages?

```
$result = mysql_query("
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            offline_access_users
    ");

    if($result){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $msg['access_token'] = $row['access_token'];
            try {
                $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $msg);
                $output .= "<p>Posting message on '". $row['name'] . "' wall success</p>";
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $output .= "<p>Posting message on '". $row['name'] . "' wall failed</p>";

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to think this out a bit.

First off, you will need to do this in a **cronjob**, that will run, for example, every 5 minutes.

After that, you need to see how you can limit for messages to not be sent more often that once per day per person(or whatever limit you want) - so you need to create an extra field `message_sent_date` in your table.

Then, you need to limit the amount of users per cronjob run.

```
// replace mysql with mysqli or PDO !!!
$result = mysqli_query($link, "
        SELECT *
        FROM offline_access_users
        ORDER BY message_sent_date ASC
        LIMIT 5
    "); // this takes the 5 users that received messages the longest time ago
```

Next, inside the `while` loop, execute this query (in the try block).

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE offline_access_users SET message_sent_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = {$row[id]}";
```

That should be it, let me know how it goes.

**The result**

This script will run every 5 minutes, and select 5 users that have not received the message (the logic here depends on what you need, so you should be a bit clearer).

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

```
$offset = 0; //Starting Point
$limit = 2;  //Number of records to work with per loop
while(1)
{
    $result = mysql_query("
        SELECT * FROM offline_access_users LIMIT $offset,$limit
    ");

    if($result){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $msg['access_token'] = $row['access_token'];
            try {
            $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $msg);
            $output .= "<p>Posting message on '". $row['name'] . "' wall success</p>";
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $output .= "<p>Posting message on '". $row['name'] . "' wall failed</p>";

            }
        }
    }
    else
        break;
    $offset = $offset + $limit;
}
```

Comment: This does exactly the same thing, and doesn't solve the problem, as this doesn't add delay between sending messages. The concept is flawed as well, because even if you added `sleep`, the script will have to run constantly, but most of the time it will wait for the `sleep` to end.